# Kernel header for version 4.8.0-32-generic were not found on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: vmware

I have installed VMware-Workstation-Full-12.5.2-4638234.x86_64.bundle. When I try to start VMWare it shows Kernel header for version 4.8.0-32-generic were not found. I am unable to find solution for this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the the version.h file needed by the VMware Tools installer have been relocated from `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux` to `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux`. If so, then it's necessary to create a symbolic link. For that:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type `ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h`
3. This will create a symbolic link, then `sudo systemctl reboot`, it should work
4. If still not working, run `bin/vmware-uninstall-tools.pl` form the `vmware-install.pl` directory and re-run `vmware-install.pl`
5. `sudo systemctl reboot`, it should work now